# How to solve classcastexception of same class for ehcache

Tags: tomcat, docker, ehcache, cas, classcastexception

using ehcache 2.10.3 for distributed CAS tickets. When I use the war that the project creates in standalone tomcat there are no issues. However, when I deploy the same on the tomcat inside a docker I get classcastexception for net.sf....RMIMessage . I am using RMI Replication as suggested in the documentation for CAS. 
Can someone help how to approach the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You most likely end up having two different Ehcache libraries, one inside your WAR, another inside Tomcat and that's causing the issue.

In order to be more specific, provide more information on the setup.